# Create JQuery-Sprites with defined color

Tags: java, jquery, image-processing, sprite

I want to generate standard JQuery-Sprites with a given color programmaticaly. Similar as in ThemeRoller the icons sprites are generated.

So my question(s): where can I find the template for JQuery sprites.

And how can I transform this template to the template with a given color ? My programing language is Java.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look a ImageMagick: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

It's got a powerful CLI for generating Sprites in all manner of ways.
I've used it successfully in commercial applications.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll check ImageMagick